# Как проверить хэш транзакции при его отправке в телеграм-бот?

Tags: python, telebot, bitcoin, blockchain

Задача - следующая:

Пользователь вписывает хэш транзакции со своего криптокошелька.
Пока хэш не будет проверен - бот не отвечает. Если введенная комбинация символов не соответствует стандартам шифрования - бот должен выдать "Неверные данные. Введите хэш еще раз".

Как сравнить введенный пользователем текст и хэш транзакции в блокчейне Биткоина?

Как автоматизировать проверку хэша транзакции в телеграм-боте?

Comment: Можно использовать api сайта blockchain.com: https://www.blockchain.com/ru/api/api_receive

Comment: Я неоднократно читал руководство оттуда, но не могу до конца понять, как на Пайтон это переписать. PHP не близок от слова "совсем" (если что, я - новичок в программировании, поэтому многое еще непонятно).

Если можете объяснить популярно - буду благодарен

Плюс не до конца понятно, как автоматизировать проверку хэша?

Comment: Помимо этого, для получения ключа для API нужен URL. А у меня - бот в Телеграмме, а не сайт